# Check If Username Exists

Tags: php, mysql

Whats the best way to check if a username exists in a MySQL table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE username='whatever'
```

read out the first result row - if the 'count' column is > 0 then the username exists.

Alternatively, in php, you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='whatever'
```

Then use mysql_num_rows (or the equivalent).

Comment: Or you can just use a select and mysql_num_rows

Comment: For speed, change the last to :

SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='whatever' LIMIT 1

Just in case you don't have a unique constraint or index

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to determine if a user exists in MySQL (i.e. a user name exists that can login to MySQL itself).

```
select user,host from mysql.user where user = 'username';
```

If you need to filter by host:

```
select user,host from mysql.user where user = 'username' and host = 'localhost';
```

These queries lets you see who has access to the MySQL database server and only is accessible if you are an administrator for a MySQL server.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'whatever' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: In a properly indexed and constrained table (unique key on username) they should be functionally identical.  Mine will do better on poorly indexed or constrained tables.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure to do it. Its faster than running the SQL via your code. I cannot anything more than just comparing it with the saved data in your table. ;-)