# Java - How To Check If Username Already Exists In a MySQL Table

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to check whether a `username` already exists in a `database` table or not.

**Java Code:**

```
if (e.getSource() == jButton2)
{
  U = jTextField1.getText();
  if (jTextField1.getText().trim().equals(""))
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Write Username !");
  } 
  else if (jPasswordField1.getText().equals(""))
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Write Password !");
  } 
  else
  {
    try {
      String Driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
      String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LoginForm"; 
      Class.forName(Driver); 
      Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "12345");
      Statement S = Conn.createStatement();
      ResultSet RS = S.executeQuery(
          "SELECT * FROM login where username ='" + U + 
          "' and Password ='" + jPasswordField1.getText() + "'");

      while (RS.next()) {
        String Username = RS.getString("Username");
        String Password = RS.getString("Password");
        String Admin = RS.getString("Admin");

        if (Username.equals(U) & Password.equals(jPasswordField1.getText()) &
          Admin.equals("0")) 
        {

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Logged In Successfully !");
          this.dispose();
          NormalUsers NU = new NormalUsers();
          break;

        } 
        else if (Username.equals(U) & 
          Password.equals(jPasswordField1.getText()) & Admin.equals("1"))
        {

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
            "Logged In Successfully , Opening Administration Panel !");

          this.dispose();
          AdminPanel AP = new AdminPanel();
          break;
        }
        else 
        {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Username Or Password!");
        }
      }
    } 
    catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

**The problem is that:**

- If there are no rows in the `database`, then there is no an error message: `Invalid Username or Password`.
- When I execute the `SQL` query manually: `SELECT * From Login` I see the row exists there, but since I filter on `password`, it doesn't get into the `while loop`.

**How should I use java to check if a username exists in a MySQL table?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this query type specially, you don't need to loop through the ResultSet.

You're trying to find one determined record. You will not have two records with the same username/password (I'm assuming the primary key of login table is the username), so just a `if(rs.next())` it's enough. If it exists, validate to check if it's an admin.

Besides, in the query you're already implying that the record must have the specified username and password, no need to test for it once the result set is returned.

Just test for the user type, if it's admin, display the accordingly message, else, do the proper.

If the `rs.next()` is not met, then the user doesn't exist, so in the `else` block, you can display the error message about the user not being found or being invalid.

Comment: If you tried with a user/password that do exists, then it's a query related issue. If you tried with a user/password that do not exists, did you put the `else` block to the `if(rs.next())` one?

Comment: thanks man
    if (RS.next() == false) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Username Or Password !");
                    } else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Correct !");

Comment: You're very welcome. A word of advice, though, pay attention to the naming convention. Remember that names starting with uppercase are for classes. Use lowercase for variables. It will help you when you work with a ton of code, believe me. Also, remember the `if` statement test for a boolean, so if `rs.next()` returns a boolean, you don't need to compare it against a `true`/`false`. `if(rs.next())` applies when there's a record on the `ResultSet`, and fails when there isn't a record, therefore executing your `else` block. Anyways, glad you get it.

Answer (score 5):

The thing you need to work on is MySQL query.  I think a query with the `WHERE` clause is what you are looking for.

Also you might want to put that code in a separate class to prevent cooking some [spaghetti code](http://aniketsweblog.blogspot.in/2013/04/spaghetti-is-tempting-but-its-better-to.html).

The link below is an answer that is related to php language, but what you need to look is the `MYSQL query` and the logic:  [Check If Username Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926989/check-if-username-exists)

**Try something like this:**

```
public String login(String uname, String password) throws Exception{

    String status=null;
    ConnectionHandler handler=new ConnectionHandler(); //class for connection
    Connection con=handler.createConnection();
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    String query="select * from loginTable where username=" +
      "\""+uname+"\""+";";  //get username

    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query); 
    String checkUser=rs.getString(1);
    String checkPass=rs.getString(2);
    if(checkUser.equals(uname) && checkPass.equals(password)){
        status="True";
    }
    else{
        status="False";
    }
    con.close();
    return status;
}
```

Using this `status` string I determine if the username validates or not.  Have the SQL do the heavy lifting (as it was designed to do) instead of coding it yourself with java.

Comment: i don't understand your answer sorry

Comment: @user2197451 see edit for answer. what I meant that it is not an issue related to language, but a MySQL query

Comment: Did you try the solution, let me know of the output

Comment: there is no output :/ ..
i tried to click the button and details are correct

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM login where username`...
Then `resultSet.getInt("total")` . If the total is greater than 0 that user already exists.
I would also use a PreparedStatement as it is less vulnerable to sql injection attacks.
Take a look at this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java .
Example of sql count ...

```
ResultSet RS = S.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM login where username ='" + U + "' and Password ='" + jPasswordField1.getText() + "'");
        while (RS.next()) {
            if( RS.getInt("total") > 0 ) {
                // user already exists
            } else {
                // user does not exist
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean a example of a Sql Injection or a example of the count? For the count do the following

Answer (score 2):

Assuming only one row is returned you can replace the while loop with an if statement. You also don't need to check the username and password after the query has been executed as this is handled by the where clause. So your query could be modified to:

```
PreparedStatement prest = Conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Admin FROM login WHERE username = ? and Password = ?");
prest.setString(1, U);
prest.setString(2, jPasswordField1.getText());
```

and then process it using an if statement:

```
if (rs.next()) {
  //Process user level (Normal or admin)
} else {
  //Incorrect login details
}
```

Comment: This query is very dangerous: it's vulnerable to trivial SQL injection. Do not use this sql; use prepared statements!

Comment: Yeah he should use prepared statements, but my point was that there was no need to use SELECT *.

Comment: Correct your answer so that it won't be vulnerable to SQL injection risks and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: While your answer is correct, it is very dangerous. See above.

Comment: Updated to use prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Java but I think you should check your `jPasswordField`, if it is a `JTextBox` no problems but if it is a `JPasswordField` then `getText()` returns a `byte[]` not string and you need  to convert the `byte[]` to `string` first.